# Stanford NER running

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanfor-NER and when I use its demo or the serialized code that was presented by @ChristopherManning, I get the following error:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Ner {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String serializedClassifier = "/local/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
    String serializedClassifier2 = "/local/stanford-ner-2015-01-30/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";

    if (args.length > 0) {
      serializedClassifier = args[0];
    }

    NERClassifierCombiner classifier = new NERClassifierCombiner(false, false, 
            serializedClassifier, serializedClassifier2);

    String fileContents = IOUtils.slurpFile("input.txt");
    List<List<CoreLabel>> out = classifier.classify(fileContents);

    int i = 0;
    for (List<CoreLabel> lcl : out) {
      i++;
      int j = 0;
      for (CoreLabel cl : lcl) {
        j++;
        System.out.printf("%d:%d: %s%n", i, j,
                cl.toShorterString("Text", "CharacterOffsetBegin", "CharacterOffsetEnd", "NamedEntityTag"));
      }
    }
  }

}
```

the error is:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to      [Ledu.stanford.nlp.util.Index
```

Comment: The code snippet that you provided is working for me using the latest version. Did you check that there are no old jar files in your classpath?

Comment: @ Sebastian Schuster  I ran it on my windows but it fails on my Ubuntu machine. complete errors are:      
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: wordFunction
 at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ObjectBankWrapper.doBasicStuff(ObjectBankWrapper.java:136)
 at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ObjectBankWrapper$WrappedIterator.next(ObjectBankWrapper.java:86)
edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyToString(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:588)
 at Ner.main(Ner.java:111)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not using the latest version because in the current version line 136 in ObjectBankWrapper.java is a comment. Please make sure that you are using the latest version and that no old jar files are in your classpath.

Comment: Yes you were right. I had an old version PosTagger in my classpath. Thanks so much!